# IMPORTXML on google sheets error- Imported content is empty

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I want to get the price from mercari, a japanese online shop.

For example, in this link, I like to get 1,488.
https://jp.mercari.com/item/m78226870756

when I copy the xpath of

```
 <span class="number">
```

I get

```
//*[@id="item-info"]/section[1]/section[1]/div[1]/mer-price//span[2]
```

Now, using google sheet importxml

```
=IMPORTXML("https://jp.mercari.com/item/m78226870756","//*[@id='item-info']/section[1]/section[1]/div[1]/mer-price//span[2]")
```

I receive a

```
#N/A Imported content is empty.
```

I would really like to know how to get the price.
I am not familiar with this at all.
Any other way other than google sheet is also welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `#N/A` error due to `importxml` (or any other import) formula does not support the scrapping of JavaScript elements. you can test this always by disabling JS for a given site and what's left can be usually imported into google sheets

[image]